# Does a Class extended from a Base which uses an Interface ever need to also use the same Interface?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, interface

This questions comes from my AS3 history, but I think the concept applies to all languages.  I can't go back to check the original code but it has been bothering me for a while and would appreciate some clarity.

I was tasked with writing a game, MyGame, that extended a GameBase class.  The template I had been told to follow required that the game use an IGame interface, but I found that that the GameBase class also used that same interface.

Lacking proper notation, I think about it like this:

```
   MyGame : GameBase
     |          |
   IGame      IGame
```

This looks redundant to me and I want to know whether it was or whether I misunderstood inheritance in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub class inherits all super types, that includes the interfaces. There's no need to implement that interface again, because it is already implemented.